# Sublime Text 3 plugin Python 3 import package from other folder

Tags: python, sublimetext3

Sublime Text 3 uses its own python3 here: `/opt/sublime_text/python3.3.zip` and I'm making a plugin and I want to import a python2.7 (python3 compatible) package from `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

So I use:

```
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')
from rauth import OAuth1Service
```

And I get this exception:

> ImportError: cannot import name OAuth1Service

So I guess it's able to find rauth but I don't know why rauth isn't able to find its imports.

Answer (score 0):

There were too many problems with using ST's python.

So I put the non-ST-related code in its own file and am using it like this:

#### main.py

```
MYPATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
OTHER = os.path.join(MYPATH, 'other.py')
p = subprocess.Popen(['python', OTHER, arg, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.wait()
if p.returncode == 11: # set with sys.exit(11)
    print('success')
else:
    print (p.communicate()[1]) # 0 is output, 1 is errors
```

#### other.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_ = sys.argv[1]
    # p = run the code
    sys.exit(p.result)
```